# Where convert strings into date?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Typical situation: I get data via http and store them into ngrx/store. But data contains strings instead of JS Date object. Where should I convert them?

1. In service `this.http(...).map(convert).subscribe(store.dispatch(new AddAction))`
2. In reducer of store `case add: convert(payload); return state`
3. Or in action:

   ```
   export class AddMany implements Action {
       readonly type = addMany

       constructor(public payload: FinishedCall[]) {
            this.payload = this.convertData(payload)
       }
   }
   ```

I think I should do it in Service, but I'm afraid of to get very large Service file

Comment: That is up to you and the business object design. If you prefer to always work with JS Date types in your typescript code then convert as early as possible to JS Date and as late as possible from JS Date to string (if that is also necessary). Create a couple of helper methods to do the conversion (if necessary) and reuse those wherever you decide to implement this.

Comment: I prefer to convert to Date as soon as possible

Comment: Ok, so then you know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do the convert function within the reducer.

Reducers should be side-effect free. This means that they should not modify things outside of their own scope. They should simply compute the next application state as a pure function of the reducer's arguments.

We can see here that we are passing in an initial state (the current number) and an Action. To handle each action, a common approach is to use a switch statement. Instead of each reducer needing to explicitly subscribe to the dispatcher, every action gets passed into each reducer, which handles the actions it's interested in and then returns the new state along to the next reducer.

hope it helps